# Deploy multiple repositories on a single domain (via proxying in Netlify)

Tags: proxy, gitlab, gatsby, netlify

I’m trying to deploy a separate blog repo to my customdomain.com/blog - exactly as described here: [[Common Issue] Can I deploy multiple repositories in a single site?](https://community.netlify.com/t/common-issue-can-i-deploy-multiple-repositories-in-a-single-site/179)

In the existing parent website I created a `_redirects` file (there was no `netlify.toml` file) and added the below code:

```
/blog/* https://blog-site.netlify.com/blog/* 200!
```

And in the blog’s repo I created a new directory called `blog` and moved all the existing files and directories inside the `blog` directory [so for instance the most basic file path is `repo-name/blog/.editorconfig`]

However when I go on customdomain.com/blog it’s not finding the page. The blog site and the existing website are both on Gitlab and deployed on the same Netlify account. They’re both Gatsby sites and the blog is just the basic Casper theme starter if that helps. Any troubleshooting pointers or things to check?
(I’m generally new so could be making a really noob mistake too fwiw)